# Creating table using another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this requirement. First I need create emp1 table like this

```
names
-------------
Hunt, Michael
Hunt, Ethan
```

By using emp1, I need to create emp2. After selecting emp2.The output will be like this.

```
FirstLast
-----------
Michael Hunt
Ethan Hunt
```

Comment: is *every* record in this *exact* format?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
create table emp2 as
select substr(name, instr(name, ', ') + 1, length(name)) as fname,
       substr(name, 1, instr(name, ', ') - 1) as lname
  from emp
```

SQL Fiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c4c15/8/0

Or for a single column:

```
create table emp2 as
select substr(name, instr(name, ', ') + 1, length(name))
       ||' '||substr(name, 1, instr(name, ', ') - 1) as flast
  from emp
```

Comment: You can CAST it as VARCHAR2(n) to mention the size as well!

Comment: I need to create single column 'firstlast'

Comment: @viki then you have to concatenate, see my edit with a query that will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
     create table emp1(names nvarchar(50));
    insert into emp1(names) values('Hunt,Michael');
    insert into emp1(names) values('Hunt,Ethan');
    create table emp2(FirstLast nvarchar(50));
    insert into emp2(FirstLast) Select names from emp1;
    select * from emp2;
   select  FirstLast,
   Replace(RIGHT(FirstLast, LEN(FirstLast) - CHARINDEX(',', FirstLast))+' '+ LEFT(FirstLast, CHARINDEX(',', FirstLast)),',','')
        AS UpdatedFirstLast
FROM Emp2
```

Comment: Sir I need to create emp2 using emp1 sir both are having single column I am new to sql please guide me

Answer (score 0):

You can try below mentioned code :

```
insert into emp2 
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTR(NAMES,INSTR(NAMES,',',1,1)+1,LENGTH(NAMES) - INSTR(NAMES,',',1,1))||' '||SUBSTR(NAMES,1,INSTR(NAMES,',',1,1)-1)) AS FirstLast FROM EMP1;
```

Comment: using emp1 I need to create emp2 sir pls guide me thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
create table emp1(names nvarchar(50));
    insert into emp1(names) values('Hunt,Michael');
    insert into emp1(names) values('Hunt,Ethan');
    select names into emp2 from emp1;
    select  names,
    Replace(RIGHT(names, LEN(names) - CHARINDEX(',', names))+' '+ LEFT(names, CHARINDEX(',', names)),',','')
    AS FirstLast
    FROM emp2
```

Comment: @viki have u got your answer ?

Comment: @viki i am not getting any error. Please copy the whole code and paste it.Then compare it with the query you are implementing, you will find error.